# an inline table valued function created in azure sa, good in use, but can't find it

Tags: azure-functions

[image]

[image]

An inline table valued function created in azure sa, good in use, but can't find it via SSMS-Programmability > Functions, since NO Table-valued Functions category,
so HOW to make Programmability > Functions > Table-valued Functions shown in Azure SA via SSMS?

Answer (score 0):

After deploying the SQL database you can create a function in the query editor.

You will have to login first though:

[image]

Refer this [article](https://sqlserverguides.com/create-stored-procedures-in-azure-sql-database/#:%7E:text=%20Azure%20SQL%20stored%20procedure%20example%20%201,query%20in%20the%20query%20editor%20window.%20More%20) on stored procedure but I think it will apply to functions too.

You can also refer this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/functions?view=sql-server-ver16)